# SharePoint Hosted App wrong URL

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

Right now i am working on SharePoint Hosted App. I have create one SharePoint Hosted App in my on-premise environment. But my App URL is like

https://localhost:44305/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fbisp12%3A1000%2Fsites%2FAppDevelopmentSite&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4569%2E1000

Instead of

http://Apps-12345678ABCDEF.ContosoApps.com

I don't know what happen or is anything wrong i have done?

**Note:** I have created self-singed certificate for app.

Answer (score 0):

By default a SharePoint App-project use IIS Express as web server. And if you deploy your App from within Visual Studio using Ctrl+F5 you will get URLs similar to https://localhost:44305

If you want to use a predefined IIS site with http://Apps-12345678ABCDEF.ContosoApps.com bound as host name then you can try this:

1. Open your web project in Visual Studio
2. Open Project Properties (right-click on the project)
3. Click on the Web section
4. Under the Servers heading change from IIS Express to Local IIS and also update the Project Url.

As an alternative you can Publish your app from the App-project.

1. Right click project and select Publish...
2. Click Package the app
3. Enter your DNS/URL in the field ***Where is your website hosted?***
4. Deploy the App to App catalog or directly to the web site